# Form value not getting assigned with addControl function inside for loop and async function

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to loop through an array, call a http request, get an array from it and assign selected object from the fetched array to a newly added Form Control in the form.

Here's what I tried.

```
for (let i = 0; i < typeaheadFields.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(async () => {
        const field = typeaheadFields[i];
        const arr = await this.contactsService
                            .getContactInfoItemArray(field.Url + '?pageSize=2147483647&offset=0&query=&orderBy=')
                            .toPromise();
        const val = arr.find(item => item.Id === primaryGuest.Id);
        const control = new FormControl(val, Validators.required);

        this.form.addControl(field.FieldName, control);
    });
}
```

and

```
(async () => {
     for (const field of typeaheadFields) {
         const arr = await this.contactsService
                            .getContactInfoItemArray(field.Url + '?pageSize=2147483647&offset=0&query=&orderBy=')
                            .toPromise();
         const val = arr.find(item => item.Id === primaryGuest.Id);
         const control = new FormControl(val, Validators.required);

         this.form.addControl(field.FieldName, control);
         this.cdr.markForCheck();
     }
})();
```

This adds a new form control to the form but the value in the form control is `null` in cases like when you check the view or use `get` function just below `addControl`. I added a debug point inside the loop. `val` and `control` is not `null` or `undefined`. They have the objects that I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by spreading the form group and appending the new control.

`this.form = new FormGroup({ ...this.form.controls, [field.FieldName]: control });`

UPDATE:

You need to be aware about subscribed events and function calls in the form. Because they'll be invalid after this.